# Java extract substring from url string

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract substring from a url string.
This is the url:

```
  https://test.tech.com/public/pi?id=635106391297495358_0_280740c3f281419b954b309b45a41d77-M_M_0_56b6f628b90b4146abbdba1de9095657
```

I want to start extracting from id=

```
  635106391297495358_0_280740c3f281419b954b309b45a41d77
```

until dash (-), and then extract the remaining substring

```
  M_M_0_56b6f628b90b4146abbdba1de9095657
```

Note that the exact domain is not the one in the above, that's just an example .

Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

this is what I've done so far:

```
  final URI uri = URI.create(result.getContents());
                    final String path = uri.getPath();
                    path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
                    Log.e("EXTRACTED", "" + path);
```

But it just gets public/pi.

Comment: Alrite, have u tried something, any regex?

Comment: @JunedAhsan yup. I tried lastIndexOf. Will update my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `uri.getPath()` returns the path component, but what you're looking for is after the ?, so what you might want to try instead is `uri.getQuery()`.

As for the matching:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("id=(.+?)-");
Matcher m = p.matcher(uri.getQuery());
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Not tested, but I think it should work. The `(.+?)` is a capturing group that tries to match characters between the `id=` and the `-`.

Comment: then the regex would be something like `id=(.+?)-(.+)`, and you would be able to call `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)`; you could always look at the documentation for [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) or [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more help. glad it works!

Answer (score 1):

One major problem is that:

```
 path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

will not modify the variable path. The reason is that String are immutable and any change to them create a new string internally. If you want to get hold of the new substring reference then you need to assign it back to `path`:

```
 path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

Now you can try more substring options

Comment: @JunedAhsan I'm still getting public/pi

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes Debug/trace your code. Variations of substring will lead u there.

Answer (score 1):

```
final URI uri = URI.create("https://test.tech.com/public/pi?id=635106391297495358_0_280740c3f281419b954b309b45a41d77-M_M_0_56b6f628b90b4146abbdba1de9095657");
    String queryString = uri.getQuery(); 
    String subString =  queryString.substring(queryString.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
    System.out.println("EXTRACTED " + subString);
```

Produces:

> EXTRACTED M_M_0_56b6f628b90b4146abbdba1de9095657

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution, which I hope is self explanatory:**

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    final String uriStr = "https://test.tech.com/public/pi?id=635106391297495358_0_280740c3f281419b954b309b45a41d77-M_M_0_56b6f628b90b4146abbdba1de9095657";
    final URI uri = URI.create(uriStr);
    final String query = uri.getQuery();
    System.out.println(String.format("EXTRACTED QUERY [%s]", query));
    final String part1 = query.substring(query.indexOf('=')+1, query.indexOf('-'));
    System.out.println(String.format("EXTRACTED PART 1 [%s]", part1));
    final String part2 = query.substring(query.indexOf('-')+1);
    System.out.println(String.format("EXTRACTED PART 2 [%s]", part2));
}
```

}*

**Here is the output:**
EXTRACTED QUERY [id=635106391297495358_0_280740c3f281419b954b309b45a41d77-M_M_0_56b6f628b90b4146abbdba1de9095657]

EXTRACTED PART 1 [635106391297495358_0_280740c3f281419b954b309b45a41d77]

EXTRACTED PART 2 [M_M_0_56b6f628b90b4146abbdba1de9095657]